# Get ListView item index

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get the row index and  pass it to a component

this is my code

```
<ListView
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData, index) =>
        <Message data={rowData} index={index}/>
     } />
```

I always get s1 string. Is this the section number? I only have one section in the ListView. Is it possible to get the index of each component in this section? In Message I want to check that the item is the first want on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can pass to your component, I think you want rowID. 
Check the [renderRow](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow) function in the documents for more information.
Right now in index you are passing the sectionID.

> (rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable

Your code  should be like this:

```
<ListView
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) =>
        <Message data={rowData} index={rowID}/>
     } />
```